# How to establish secure connection between windows application and licence server?

Tags: c#, .net, security, ssl, https

I'm developing windows service that will install on customer's PC and license server which will be placed on Azure and will manage applications licence. 
I need establish secure connection between two application over the Internet but I'm afraid some customer can look at successful response from licence server and make fake response to windows service each time it will be called. I'm thinking about HTTPS protocol. 
What could you suggest in this situation?

Comment: It’s impossible to fully protect against this sort of thing. The only way would be to embed a secret in the client application used to protect the communication between the client and server, however no matter how well you try to obfuscate the secret, a determined attacker will always be able to extract it. Further, it would also be possible for an attacker to simply disassemble/decompile the executable and just skip the license check completely.

Comment: @DaveM I know that attackers can disassemble files but I ask from side of replacement licence server by fake one, for example with proxy server. How modern application with an online lisence avoid that?

Comment: You could “pin” the SSL cert/public key of your license server in your application, but again it would trivial to bypass this.